# How to include a curser indication while drawing a line on a picture?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I want to draw a line on a picture while having an ellipse following the mouse at the mouse position. I have developed the following code, the ellipse always draw on the picture.

```
function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  //background(220);
  line(pmouseX, pmouseY, mouseX, mouseY);
  fill(255, 0, 0);
  ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 7, 7);
}
```

You can see that the ellipse is always draw on the picture. How can I remove the ellipse after it shows once?

I am expecting a line is drawn on the picture while an ellipse is shown at the mouse position. The ellipse should not draw on the image, I only follow the mouse location, however, the line will draw on the picture.

Comment: sorry I could not understand what you want If you want the ellipse to be drawn only once, put it in the setup, but it will immediately disappear when the first draw is called. Then I don't understand `drawn on the picture while a curser indication is at the mouse position`  The mouse cursor will always be at the mouse position, that's the definition of mouse position.  And then when you say `The curser indicator should not draw on the image` you mean you don't want the mouse cursor to be shown? You can disable the mouse cursor with [noCursor()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/noCursor)

Comment: @sembei Norimaki Thank you for you comment. What I mean is I want to draw a line on a picture. When I am drawing the line, I also want a ellipse to act as a mouse indicator. There for at position (mouseX, mouseY) there should be an ellipse following the mouse curser.

Comment: that's what your code does. you are drawing an ellipse where the mouse cursor is. I don't understand what is the problem you are asking. If you draw the ellipse only once as you say in the question then it won't follow your mouse.

Comment: @sembei Norimaki, I just want one ellipse follow the mouse. It should not draw on the picture (now there are a lot of ellipse). The ellipse act as a mouse indicator. It should not draw on the picture. It should act like a cursor. 

What I mean the ellipse appear only once is it should follow the mouse position. But I don't want a lot of ellipse draw on the picture.

Comment: uncomment the background(220) line. But that will also erase the lines. So I think I understand your problem now. You want a cursor to be an ellipse, and at the same time keep what you have drawn in the canvas, so using background won't work for you. Is that what you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand now what you want.

If you uncomment the background instruction, you will erase the lines drawn so far. If you comment the background the lines will remain, but also the ellipses.

So, for that you need the instruction [cursor()](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/cursor) that allows you to use a custom mouse cursor.

So, what I would suggest is: Create an image file that contains an ellipse and the background is transparent.

Specify that you want a cursor from a file, by doing

```
cursor("myCursorImage.png")
```

Take a look at the reference of the cursor that I provided in a link to see the different parameters you can pass to `cursor()`